# How to setup hijri datepicker by jquery datepicker or bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to setup datepicker for hijri date.I can use jquery datepicker or bootstrap datepicker. however I wrote this code

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background:#ddd">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="name"   />
    <script>    
        ; (function ($) {
            $.fn.datepicker.dates['ar'] = {
                days: ["الأحد", "الاثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت", "الأحد"],
                daysShort: ["أحد", "اثنين", "ثلاثاء", "أربعاء", "خميس", "جمعة", "سبت", "أحد"],
                daysMin: ["ح", "ن", "ث", "ع", "خ", "ج", "س", "ح"],
                months: ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو", "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"],
                monthsShort: ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو", "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"],
                today: "هذا اليوم",
                rtl: true
            };
        }(jQuery));
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            'regional':'ar'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but do not work . I see number website that datepicker has Georgian date but days name is arabic.I need to days name is arabic and datepicker date are hijri together.

Note : After select date ,  datepicker should be fill by hijri date.

How to do this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify the question: I think you mean [Gregorian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), not [Georgian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `language` option instead of `regional` (see snippet below).

```js
$.fn.datepicker.dates['ar'] = {
                days: ["الأحد", "الاثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت", "الأحد"],
                daysShort: ["أحد", "اثنين", "ثلاثاء", "أربعاء", "خميس", "جمعة", "سبت", "أحد"],
                daysMin: ["ح", "ن", "ث", "ع", "خ", "ج", "س", "ح"],
                months: ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو", "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"],
                monthsShort: ["يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو", "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"],
                today: "هذا اليوم",
                rtl: true
            };
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  language:'ar',
  format: 'yyyy, MM dd'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To change displayed date format set datepicker [`format`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format).

Comment: OK datepicker display text in arabic language but I need to get hijri date. Now we can get  Georgian date !!!!

Comment: @programmer138200, use [format](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) option.

Comment: ok format option can format  date and I can convert Georgian date to jalali date but datepicker is Georgian yet.The datepicker should  be jalali

Comment: @programmer138200, what do you mean by "The datepicker should be jalali"? Could you clarify your question and give screenshots or examples from another web-sites?

Comment: I post images. Please see its.

Comment: @programmer138200, do you want to make Gregorian/Hijri converter using by single input control? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Only Hijri  DatePicker  not convertor